# Insert 6000 rows in Couchbase, but not stored success

Tags: .net, memcached, generic-list, couchbase

I generated 6000 objects in List, and stored List into Couchbase with memcached, but the Store method returned "false" without any messages, I don't know why 6000 rows data can not be stored but 2000 rows data works.

Comment: Yes, it's so very easy to diagnose problems from vague problem reports and no code.

Comment: Do you see anything on the log files?

Comment: How big (in MB) is the 6000 objects in a list. Couchbase has a 20MB limit per key.

Comment: Yes, the size of 6000 objects is greater than 1BM, the Bucket Type is Memcached, how to set 20MB limit per key?

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase is not designed to store large lists of data as one object. You cannot change the 20MB limit. Therefore, to store your objects, you need to store each one separately.

See [here](http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/change-maximum-item-size) for more information.